# Since meteor 1.2 after building APK is missing

Tags: android, meteor

I'm running: `meteor build ~/deployment --server=my-app.meteor.com`

But when I check `~/deployment/android` it contains only `project` and `README`. Where has the APK gone?

Comment: do you have the android sdk installed on your system and is the ANDROID_HOME environment variable set?

Comment: I have SDK platform 22 installed, and `echo $ANDROID_HOME` prints the path to the sdk

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Eventually I found it somewhere in the folder tree. It wasn't copied automatically because there are two files, because of my use of CrossWalk.

See elaborations here:
https://github.com/meteor/meteor/issues/5274

And how to upload two apks to play store:

https://software.intel.com/sites/default/files/managed/9a/72/Intel_Walkthrough_GP-Multiple_APK_Submissions.pdf

Command to copy one of the files:

`cp my_build_dir/android/project/build/outputs/apk/android-armv7-release-unsigned.apk unaligned.apk`